How do I modify friction to make a Spinning Circle stop at a specific angle?
I am creating a Spinning Wheel game in Javascript. When a button is clicked, a random velocity is set. When the stop-button is clicked, a friction is applied to the velocity. When fricition is activated, every frame this happens:
// friction = 0.98;
velocity = velocity * friction;
theAngle = theAngle + velocity;

When velocity < 0.002, the wheel will stop.
What I want to do here is, is modify the friction variable so that the Wheel stops at an angle I can pick myself.
So far I have succeeded in calculating the stopAngle, and the number of frames the wheel spins.
let angle = theAngle // the current angle (before stopping)
let speed = velocity;
let frames = 0;
let willStopAtAngle = angle;
const targetSpeed = 0.002;
while (speed > targetSpeed) {
speed *= config.friction; 
frames = frames + 1; 
angle = angle + speed; 
}

I have also calculated the angle I want the wheel to stop, and I know this is correct.
const diff = stopAngle - (angle % (Math.PI * 2));
const actualStopAngle = angle + stopAngle

I feel like I know enough, but I just don't know how to calculate the right friction
friction = (actualStopAngle - theAngle)/frames // I thought something like this might work;

Thanks!

Why not use a constant start speed and friction, and change the start angle?

@Cam I was about to reply that you didn't understand my question, but you saved me haha. I can just add the difference between the estimated angle and the angle I want to the current angle before applying the friction. If the wheel is spinning fast enough, this isn't visible and works perfectly. Thanks!

Have a look at my recent answer. In short: make a guess until you are close enough.
